# FormData not being read by laravel on backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, file-upload, eloquent

This qn is related to vue and alravel, I try to make and api request on vue with `const response = await http.put("api/v1/vehicles/" + vehicleId,formData);`. I see the data going on payload, But when i DO `dd($request->all())` It shows empty

```
async update(vehicleId, data) {
  try {
    let formData = new FormData();
    (data.files ?? []).forEach((file, key) => {
      formData.append("files[]", file);
    });
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (key !== "files" && value !== null) formData.append(key, value);
    });
    const response = await http.put(
      "api/v1/vehicles/" + vehicleId,
      formData
    );
    return Promise.resolve(response.formData);
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
},
```

When I hit url with   `const response = await http.put("api/v1/vehicles/" + vehicleId,data);` It shows on `$request->all()`. I need to add formData to attach the fiels. Is it because put request doesnot read formData??

I saw a method spoofing and I did this

```
        let vehicle_data = { _method: "PUT", form: formData };
    const response = await http.post(
      "api/v1/vehicles/" + vehicleId,
      vehicle_data
    );
```

BUt it gives null on form?

Comment: Try to set the Content-Type header to multipart/form-data if you are uploading files

Answer (score 0):

PUT and PATCH request types require adding a `_method` property in payload and using `.post` instead `.put`

Said that, you should do this:

```js
async update(vehicleId, data) {
  try {
    let formData = new FormData();
    (data.files ?? []).forEach((file, key) => {
      formData.append("files[]", file);
    });
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (key !== "files" && value !== null) formData.append(key, value);
    });
    formData.append("_method", "PUT") 
    const response = await http.post(
      "api/v1/vehicles/" + vehicleId,
      formData
    );
    return Promise.resolve(response.formData);
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
},
```

Please note that I've changed request to `http.post()` and added `formData.append("_method", "PUT")`

Your API will recognize it as a PUT request and also grab payload correctly.

The same should be done for PATCH requests.